# Save excel as PDF in current folder using current workbook name

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

Trying to save a set of sheets from a workbook to PDF format to the same folder and using workbook name.

After recording the macro with all the steps went back and tried to replace the pieces of the code by what I found in some of this forum's threads but now it is not working.

Current version is below.
What did I break?

```
SaveToPDF Macro

Sheets(Array("AUDIT Info", "REVIEW", "FILES", "WARNINGS", "PURGE", "NonBIM", _
    "Clashes", "ViewsManagement")).Select
Sheets("AUDIT Info").Activate
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
Sheets("AUDIT Info").Select
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SaveSheetsasPDF()

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("AUDIT Info", "REVIEW", "FILES", "WARNINGS", "PURGE", "NonBIM", "Clashes", "ViewsManagement")).Select

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: It is working. Thank you very much. But the created PDF is including the [filename].xlms.pdf extension. How can I remove the "xlms" bit?

Comment: got it just added. 

Dim NameOfWorkbook
NameOfWorkbook = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, (InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))

Answer (score 0):

You will get an error if before running the macro one of the needed sheets will be selected/activated.. that's why you need to add the first line
sheets(1).select

where the first sheet isn't in your array