# Export to PDF when document is going to expand

Tags: excel, vba

I have got to know how to export the document to the PDF.

[Save excel as PDF in current folder using current workbook name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43345109/save-excel-as-pdf-in-current-folder-using-current-workbook-name)

Here is a good solution, but it refers only to static file.

I tried something like here:

```
    Sub SavetoPDF()

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20)).Select

     ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name, _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True


   End Sub
```

But having 20 sheets in the array such this is an awkward thing.

On top of that, when I put 25 sheets (while my document has 23 only), then I got that script is out of range.

DOes it mean, that if I insert some new sheet into my document, then some at the end will be omitted.

Is the solution allowing to save full Excel document as a PDF (in VBA) for flexible amount of sheets?

Comment: If I understand correctly, your issue is that you want all the sheets in your document selected? This can be done with using `ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Select` instead of your awkward array. Unless you want only specific sheets, or you want to skip certain ones, there is no need for the array.

Comment: Please note also, using select is bad form to begin with, and you could get around this entirely with `Thisworkbook.Sheets.ExportAsFixedFormat` etc.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much.

DO you know how it works in case of sheet colours?

Comment: Sheet colours shouldn't influence this code whatsoever. But if you want to select the sheets based on their colour, this is a completely different question altogether. This will likely will need to be done with a loop and if statements, and a different array. It's best to start a new question with your updated requirements.

Comment: If you have 25 sheets and want to pdf 23 of them. In your code, hide the two sheets you don't want in the PDF then pdf the entire workbook, then unhide the sheets at the end.