# Saving document as a PDF with modified filename

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I am trying to save my Excel file as a PDF but with custom file name.

I would only add a piece to the prompted filename from the Excel file.

According to the queries here:

[Save excel as PDF in current folder using current workbook name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43345109/save-excel-as-pdf-in-current-folder-using-current-workbook-name)

[Save excel as PDF in current folder using current workbook name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43345109/save-excel-as-pdf-in-current-folder-using-current-workbook-name/43345229)

My code looks as follows:

```
Sub DPPtoPDF()

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Select

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
      ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name, _
      Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
      IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

    Sheets("Frontsheet").Select

End Sub
```

From this code we know the PDF filename will be the Excel filename.

I tried something like this:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Select

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= &fName $ "-Route-Aprooval.pdf" _
  ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name, _
  Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
  IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

I get an error as per in the picture below.

[image]

I can see something is up, as my code is turning red.

The code:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Select

 ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _ 
   " &fName $ "-Route-Aprooval.pdf""
 ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name, _
   Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
   IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

also doesn't work.

Any code behind the `Filename:=` destroys whole code.

I want to keep the name as in Excel, but add another part of the name after dash (per the image above).

Where should I place my new output filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below.

```
Sub DPPtoPDF()
  Dim Custom_Name as string
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Select

  Custom_Name= ThisWorkbook.Name & "-route approval" & ".pdf"

   ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
   ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Custom_Name, _
   Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
   IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

   Sheets("Frontsheet").Select

   End Sub
```

Comment: Hi looks good, although I want to keep the same name as it stands in Excel like: "Openreach pack.xlsm" and when saving as a PDF i want to add "-route approval" and get the output name as: "Openreach pack - route aprooval.pdf". Is that possible?

Comment: Works, that's what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: How about if I want to have a suffix like this:

Custom_Name = & "RA" &  ThisWorkbook.Name  ".pdf" It returns: Expected end of statement

Comment: You need "&" after  ThisWorkbook.name